How to add url to whole pdf?
I have a pdf file that is about 100 pages. I want to add a link on the whole pdf(not a specific area of the PDF) so that wherever you click on the pdf, you will be brought to that url. I know I can use a PDF editing tool such as Acrobat to add a link but it requires you to select an area, which is inconvenient.

@KJ No, I do not mean to link to another PDF such as A.PDF. I want to link to an external website such as "google.com" on every page of my PDF.

What research have you done regarding this prior to asking? How are you currently creating PDFs? You've tagged a few different PDF creation utilities, but the ones you've tagged take documents from other sources and convert them to PDF. Have you created a full-page link in these source docs? Do they convert?

Acrobat has a macro function, called Actions. This may be your best option, unless another tool offers macros. https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/links-attachments-pdfs.html
